# What are the requirements for a SOLR field to be eligible for facet range query?

Tags: solr, solrnet

Exception during facet.range of id org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to range facet on field:id{type=string,properties=indexed,stored,omitNorms,omitTermFreqAndPositions,sortMissingLast,required, required=true}

This is the error I'm encountering when i try to do a facet range over ID field of my document. What am I doing wrong here in terms of defining this field in the schema? Have i violated any rules for eligibility for facet range query?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the facet.range option (new in Solr 3.1), [the docs say](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Facet_by_Range) "one can use the Range Faceting feature on any date field or any numeric field that supports range queries" but your field type is a string.